# CSS with Floated DIV Elements

Tags: html, css

I believe I have a very unique problem. I am trying to create a menu and basically I have some floated child div's inside the main menu holding div at the top of a web page. The problem is that I need to have the parent element have an automatic height because I want it to be dynamic just in-case I change the padding on the menu buttons (child DIV's). Also, the parent has a width of 100% and a child inside of it that has an automatic width with a max-width set so that I can basically have the left and right child menu buttons inside of it come together when the page is sized smaller. However all is working well until you resize the page to the point where the left right right menu portions come together, then all of the child menu buttons want to stack instead of automatically create a vertical scrollbar for the main page.

I don't know if this will pose a problem because I plan on using media queries later to automatically switch up the CSS for mobile compatibility. However, I would like to find a solution to this problem. If I need to post all of my code to get the right answer please let me know and I will do.

Thank you so much.

Oh and by the way, I have searched on a solution to this for about an hour and nothing is working. I may as well post the code below because I really want to find a solution.

The HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main-nav" class="float-left">
            <ul id="main-nav-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="main-menu-button">
                    <a href="#" data-description="Since 1976">
                        Pardee Electric
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main-nav" class="float-right">
            <ul ud="main-nav-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="main-menu-button" class="float-right">
                    <a href="#">
                        Get in Touch
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="main-menu-button" class="float-right">
                    <a href="#">
                        Residential
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="main-menu-button" class="float-right">
                    <a href="#">
                        Commercial
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="main-menu-button" class="float-right">
                    <a href="#">
                        Industrial
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
/* body data */

body {
margin-top: 0px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

ul {
list-style: disc;
}

/* header data */

#header {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: #456DC0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#wrapper {
width: auto;
max-width: 1024px;
height: auto;
background: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix:after { 
content: " ";
display: block; 
height: 0; 
clear: both;
margin-top: 0;
}

#main-nav-menu {

}

#main-nav {
width: auto;
height: auto;
position: relative;
}

#main-nav ul, #main-nav .menu {
margin: 0px;
}

#main-nav li {
width: auto;
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
display: inline;
}

#main-nav a {
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
position: relative;
letter-spacing: 0px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
display: block;
color: #F0F0F0;
z-index: 98;
-webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease, border .2s ease, color .4s ease,          opacity .2s ease-in-out;
background-color: #4186D2;
}

#main-nav a:active {
background-color: #000000;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
background-color: #333333;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.float-right {
float: right;
}

.float-left {
float: left;
}
```

[Demo in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZQ6q/)

Hopefully the css posted OK. I am new to Stack.

Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by "stack instead of automatically creating a vertical scroll bar". Could you be a little more clear on what exact behavior you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am also a little confused. I would like to comment that you also shouldn't use an ID more than once. But more importantly, for this instance, I think it would help a lot if you didn't have your elements so deeply nested. There's really no reason at all to have the left nav element nested four layers deep.

Comment: there is no unique problem.! Amen!

Comment: I meant to automatically create a horizontal scrollbar for the whole page. Not vertical. Like when someone chooses to unmax the screen and then size it down the whole way I don't want the menu buttons to stack when they come together I just want the page to create a horizontal scroller for the entire site, but because the menu buttons are all floated elements and the parents heights are auto they are wanting to stack up instead. I want to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give `class="clearfix"` to `id="wrapper"`.